# See Javascript Errors raised by IOS Safari

Tags: javascript, debugging, mobile-safari

I found some old questions about the very same issue: Safari on IOS does not display or output anywhere javascript errors. Its 2018: Without an Apple computer is there any way to diagnose js errors in safari?

My current one is obviously a compile error. As for now, I try to locate it with setting alerts and commenting code out. How tedious.

Comment: just found this, working on it: https://washamdev.com/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows/

Answer (score 1):

I followed this tutorial (https://washamdev.com/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows/) and succeeded. While the debugging experience is very poor compared to common browser debugging, it is super-excellent compared to the js error swallowing behavior of ios safari.